# Angular 8 Reactive form automatically adds a row on pressing Enter key

Tags: angular

I am working on a project on Angular 8 and I have used  ReactFrom but it automatically calls a function addNewItem() and adds a new row when pressed Enter key on any field in a row.
I have also used AutocompleteLibModule from angular-ng-autocomplete for auto-complete.

**supplier-bill-component.html**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <h2 class="text-center display-3 mb-2">Supplier Bill</h2>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <form [formGroup]="userTable">
        <table class="table table-border">
          <thead class="text-nowrap">
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <th>Comp</th>
            <th>Pack</th>
            <th>Batch</th>
            <th>EXP</th>
            <th>MRP</th>
            <th>Rate</th>
            <th>Qty</th>
            <th>Bonus</th>
            <th>SGST</th>
            <th>CGST</th>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <ng-container
              formArrayName="tableRows"
              *ngFor="let group of getFormControls.controls; let i = index"
            >
              <tr [formGroupName]="i">
                <td>
                  <ng-autocomplete
                    #ngAutoCompleteStatic
                    [data]="medicines"
                    formControlName="productName"
                    [initialValue]=""
                    [searchKeyword]="keyword"
                    (inputChanged)="onChangeSearch($event)"
                    [itemTemplate]="itemTemplateStatic"
                    matInput
                  >
                  </ng-autocomplete>

                  <ng-template #itemTemplateStatic let-item>
                    <a [innerHTML]="item.productName"></a>
                  </ng-template>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <mat-form-field style="width: 60px !important;">
                    <input matInput type="text" formControlName="company" />
                  </mat-form-field>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <mat-form-field style="width: 60px !important;">
                    <input matInput type="text" formControlName="pack" />
                  </mat-form-field>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <mat-form-field style="width: 65px !important;">
                    <input matInput type="text" formControlName="batch" />
                  </mat-form-field>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <mat-form-field style="width: 50px !important;">
                    <input matInput type="text" formControlName="exp" />
                  </mat-form-field>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <mat-form-field style="width: 60px !important;">
                    <input matInput type="text" formControlName="mrp" />
                  </mat-form-field>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <mat-form-field style="width: 60px !important;">
                    <input matInput type="text" formControlName="rate" />
                  </mat-form-field>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <mat-form-field style="width: 50px !important;">
                    <input matInput type="text" formControlName="quantity" />
                  </mat-form-field>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <mat-form-field style="width: 60px !important;">
                    <input matInput type="text" formControlName="bonus" />
                  </mat-form-field>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <mat-form-field style="width: 30px !important;">
                    <input matInput type="text" formControlName="sgst" />
                  </mat-form-field>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <mat-form-field style="width: 30px !important;">
                    <input matInput type="text" formControlName="cgst" />
                  </mat-form-field>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <mat-icon class="delete" (click)="deleteRow(i)"
                    >delete_forever</mat-icon
                  >
                  <!-- <mat-icon class="done" (click)="doneRow(group)"
                    >done</mat-icon
                  > -->
                </td>
                <td>
                  <button
                    mat-raised-button
                    type="submit"
                    (click)="addNewItem()"
                  >
                    Add row
                  </button>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <!-- <tr *ngIf="!group.get('isEditable').value">
                <td>
                  {{ group.get("name").value }}
                </td>
                <td>
                  {{ group.get("email").value }}
                </td>
                <td>
                  {{ group.get("email").value }}
                </td>
                <td>
                  {{ group.get("bloodGroup").value }}
                </td>
                <td>
                  {{ group.get("mobNumber").value }}
                </td>
                <td>
                  <mat-icon class="edit" (click)="editRow(group)"
                    >edit</mat-icon
                  >
                </td>
              </tr> -->
            </ng-container>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="action-container">
          <!-- <button mat-raised-button type="submit" (click)="addNewItem()">
            Add row
          </button> -->
          <button
            mat-raised-button
            [disabled]="userTable.invalid"
            type="submit"
            (click)="submitForm()"
          >
            Submit
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**supplier-bill-component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { FormArray, FormGroup, FormBuilder } from "@angular/forms";
import { Observable, of } from "rxjs";
import { startWith, switchMap, delay, map } from "rxjs/operators";
import { MatOptionSelectionChange } from "@angular/material/core";
import { ApiService } from "../api.service";
import { MedicineService } from "../medicine.service";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: "app-supplier-bill",
  templateUrl: "./supplier-bill.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./supplier-bill.component.css"],
})
export class SupplierBillComponent implements OnInit {
  userTable: FormGroup;
  control: FormArray;
  mode: boolean;
  touchedRows: any;
  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private api: ApiService,
    private medicine: MedicineService,
    private router: Router
  ) {}
  keyword = "productName";

  public medicines = <any>[];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.touchedRows = [];
    this.userTable = this.fb.group({
      tableRows: this.fb.array([]),
    });
    this.addNewItem();
  }

  ngAfterOnInit() {
    this.control = this.userTable.get("tableRows") as FormArray;
  }

  initiateForm(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      productName: [""],
      company: [""],
      pack: [""],
      batch: [""],
      exp: [""],
      mrp: [""],
      rate: [""],
      quantity: [""],
      bonus: [""],
      sgst: [""],
      cgst: [""],
    });
  }

  addNewItem() {
    const control = this.userTable.get("tableRows") as FormArray;
    control.push(this.initiateForm());
  }

  deleteRow(index: number) {
    const control = this.userTable.get("tableRows") as FormArray;
    control.removeAt(index);
  }

  editRow(group: FormGroup) {
    group.get("isEditable").setValue(true);
  }

  doneRow(group: FormGroup) {
    group.get("isEditable").setValue(false);
  }

  saveUserDetails() {
    console.log(this.userTable.value);
  }

  get getFormControls() {
    const control = this.userTable.get("tableRows") as FormArray;
    return control;
  }

  submitForm() {
    const control = this.userTable.get("tableRows") as FormArray;
    this.touchedRows = control.controls
      .filter((row) => row.touched)
      .map((row) => row.value);
    console.log(this.touchedRows);
  }
  toggleTheme() {
    this.mode = !this.mode;
  }
  onProductChange(i) {
    let p = this.userTable.get("tableRows").get("");
    console.log(i);
  }

  onChangeSearch(query: string) {
    if (!query) return;
    this.medicine.searchMedicine(query).subscribe((med: any) => {
      // this.medicines = med;
      // console.log(med.medicines);
      this.medicines = med.medicines;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Please reduce the code to what is relevant. Often times you will find the issue.

Comment: button type of add new should be a button instead of submit

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a button which explicitly does the submit of `addNewItem`, and `submitForm` you could do something like below:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="return false">
```

**OR**, disable your button which won't trigger the addNewItem until everything is filled **OR** check if the form is valid before triggering `addNewItem`

```
if (this.myform.valid) {
  console.log("Form Submitted!");
}
```